# Push notifications when updated item

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

When an item has been updated, I want the user to get a notification. I have tried all kinds of stuff but feel like I almost have it but I don't get any notification.

I have made a function for the update in cloud functions that seems to work (Something kind of good happens when an item updates, as I can see in the log). I have tried to subscribe to item id and items but no differ..

```dart
  Future<List<TaskList>> getItems() async{
    List <Item> Items = [];
    var snap = await Firestore.instance
        .collection('Items')
        .getDocuments();
    for (var doc in snap.documents) {
      Item item = new Item.fromDocument(doc);
      Items.add(item);
      FirebaseMessaging().subscribeToTopic(item.postID);
    }
    return tasklists;
  }
```

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();
const fcm = admin.messaging();

exports.sendToTopic = functions.firestore
  .document('items/{itemID}')
  .onUpdate((change, context) => {
    const item = change.after.data();

    const payload = {
      notification: {
        title: item.name,
        body: `${item.name} has been updated!`
      }
    };

    return fcm.sendToTopic('items', payload);
  });
```

I also have the init for flutter notification with the firebase messaging.
I get no errors, just nothing happens when I update an item...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step in debugging is always to try and isolate the problem. Right now you don't know whether the problem is in your Flutter app, or in the Cloud Functions code.

If you [send a message to the same topic from the Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/notification), does it arrive? If so, you know the problem is in your server-side code, and you can remove the Flutter code from the equation. If the message then doesn't arrive to, first focus on making that work, and only then move on to the Cloud Functions code.

By isolating the problem in this way, you reduce the scope of what you need to consider. It's also the best way to ensure we can help here on Stack Overflow, because we have to consider fewer potential problems. For more on this, I highly recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which describes something similar to the above, and many more on how to best get help here.